# Google Charts Not Working When It is Multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have code as below:

```
var width = $(document).width();
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var general = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    var terming = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    var categorizing = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    general.addColumn("string", "property");
    general.addColumn("number", "value");

    general.addRows([
        ["Tamamlanan", 128],
        ["Kalan", 800]
    ]);

    terming.addColumn("string", "property");
    terming.addColumn("number", "value");

    terming.addRows([
        ["Tamamlanan", 128],
        ["Kalan", 800]
    ]);

    categorizing.addColumn("string", "property");
    categorizing.addColumn("number", "value");

    categorizing.addRows([
        ["Tamamlanan", 128],
        ["Kalan", 800]
    ]);


    var options_12 = {
        "width": width/1,
        "height": 250
    };

    var options_6 = {
        "width": width/3,
        "height": 250
    };

    var general = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('general'));
    var terming = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('terming'));
    var categorizing = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('categorizing'));

    general.draw(general, options_12);
    terming.draw(terming, options_6);
    categorizing.draw(categorizing, options_6);
}
```

However, multiple `DataTable()` type does not work and it raises error as below:

> You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView

Should I do multiple `drawChart()` function to draw multiple charts? It is strange it did not work. [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erayerdin/qfL1or3L/1/) if you want to look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the data with the chart so you add a chart to a chart:

```
var general = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var terming = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var categorizing = new google.visualization.DataTable();
.....
var general = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('general'));
var terming = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('terming'));
var categorizing = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('categorizing'));

general.draw(general, options_12);
terming.draw(terming, options_6);
categorizing.draw(categorizing, options_6);
```

Use different variable names to fix this. For example:

```
var general = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var terming = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var categorizing = new google.visualization.DataTable();
.....
var generalChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('general'));
var termingChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('terming'));
var categorizingChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('categorizing'));

generalChart.draw(general, options_12);
termingChart.draw(terming, options_6);
categorizingChart.draw(categorizing, options_6);
```

Comment: Oh, goddamn, how can I miss that? Thanks, I'll fix it right away.